# ¿Cómo solucionó este error PHP: move_uploaded_file() failed to open stream: No such file or directory?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando subir un archivo a mi directorio por medio de `html` y lo manipulo desde el servidor con `php` de tal forma de que quede guardado en el directorio que yo le indique, pero no he podido, el archivo me llega y cuándo lo intento de la manera en que me lo indica la [pagina](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php), pero no funciona, me salta este error:

> **Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(/Jomar/induccion/documents/mision, vision/OBJETIVOS JOMAR INVERSIONES SAS 2019.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\controllers\UploadFiles.php** on line **9**
>   
>   **Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php32BA.tmp' to '/Jomar/induccion/documents/mision, vision/OBJETIVOS JOMAR INVERSIONES SAS 2019.pdf' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\controllers\UploadFiles.php** on line **9**

Este es el código `php`:

```
<?php 
    require_once "../controllers/FilesController.php";

    $dir = "/Jomar/induccion/documents/";
    print_r($_FILES);
    if($_FILES["mision_vision"] != null){
        $fichero = "{$dir}mision, vision/".basename($_FILES["mision_vision"]["name"]);
        FilesController::deleteFiles($dir."mision, vision/");
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mision_vision"]["tmp_name"], $fichero)){
            echo "Subido correctamente";
        }else{
            echo "Error al intentar subir";
        }
    }
?>
```

Captura de los directorios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La respuesta al hacer `var_dump` y el `[error]`

```
 array(1) {
  ["mision_vision"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(40) "OBJETIVOS JOMAR INVERSIONES SAS 2019.pdf"
    ["type"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(23) "C:\xampp\tmp\php303.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(207419)
  }
}

Error al intentar subir: 0
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

```
<?php 
    require_once "../controllers/FilesController.php";
    define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

    $dir = "/Jomar/induccion/documents/";
    print_r($_FILES);
    if(isset($_FILES["mision_vision"]) && $_FILES["mision_vision"] != null){
        $fichero = SITE_ROOT."{$dir}".basename($_FILES["mision_vision"]["name"]);
        FilesController::deleteFiles($dir."mision, vision/");
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mision_vision"]["tmp_name"], $fichero)){
            echo "Subido correctamente";
        }else{
            echo "Error al intentar subir";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99902/discussion-on-question-by-daxtter77-como-soluciono-este-error-php-move-uploade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto, lo que hice para resolver el problema fue poner `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, después de buscar exhaustivamente llegué a la respuesta desde este [foro](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/move-uploaded-file-cannot-open-stream-no-file-or-directory-exists-in-xampp-mac/256495) (está en inglés) de igual manera muestro la forma en la que lo apliqué para solucionar mi problema.

```
$dir = "/Jomar/induccion/documents/";
    if(isset($_FILES["mision_vision"]) && $_FILES["mision_vision"] != null){
        $fichero = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."{$dir}mision, vision/";
        if(FilesController::deleteFiles($fichero)){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mision_vision"]["tmp_name"], $fichero.basename($_FILES["mision_vision"]["name"]))){
                echo "Subido correctamente";
            }else{
                echo "Error al intentar subir";
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias a [@A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) por su ayuda, espero que a alguien también le sirva.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Cuando te dije que pusieras la ruta absoluta intuía que no estaba tomando la ruta correcta.